# Consulta Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Tengo unpequeño problema y encuentro unasolución.

***tengo que  sacar el nombre de una persona y con el nombre del colegio***

```
    DB_Entities db = new DB_Entities();   // es generada por el Entitie framework
    public JsonResult GetPersona(string codPersona)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(codPersona);

        var persona = (from pe in db.Persona
                       join co in db.Colegio on pe.CodColegio equals co.IdColegio
                       where pe.CodPersona == id
                       select new
                       {
                           NombreCompleto = pe.NombreCompleto,
                           Colegio = co.Nombre
                       }).FirstOrDefault();

        return new JsonResult { Data = persona, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como esta definidio db.colegio?

Comment: Que exactamente necesitas de esa consulta?

Comment: @gbianchi me lo  genera el entitie  framework al hacer la conexión con VS

Comment: @VicenteAlmea Tengo que sacar el nombre de la persona y el nombre del  colegio,  puesto que los dos estan en diferentes tablas

Comment: Probaste limpiar la solucion y recompilar?

Comment: o mira aca: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15666646/73749

Comment: Actualiza el modelo, si te sigue dando problema, entonces actualiza la pregunta pero, agregando la estructura de las clases Persona y Colegio que te genera el entity framework asi podemos ver como estan generadas y verificar si es que no se esta duplicando la propiedad IdColegio.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me gustan más las expresiones landas para las consultas LINQ espero te sea de utilidad.

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(codPersona);

var persona = db.Persona.Include(p => p.Colegio).FirstOrDefault(p => p.CodPersona == id);
```

luego ya puedes acceder a `persona.Colegio.Nombre` en caso de que necesites el nombre del colegio.

Comment: como lo  haría ??

Comment: tal y como se ve

Comment: El "problema" de la notación funcional de linq cuando se utiliza en sql es que luego empiezas a utilizar extensiones de linq que no son soportadas o no se pueden trasladar a sql. Linq en versión quey limita mas lo que puedes usar y es mas "compatible" con sql